# How to add a distance (in kilometers) to a location coordinate which is in degrees and minutes to obtain new location coordinate in a java?

Tags: geolocation, maps, automatic-ref-counting, degrees, wgs84

I am writing a java program to generate a calculated distance from a mathematical formula. I want to add this value to a location coordinate value obtained from google maps in order to get the new location coordinate.How can i add the distance to geo-location in my program?

Comment: Requests for libraries or other third-party resources are off-topic here.

Comment: well,thanks ill have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

to do the conversions between geoloaction coordinates and distances in meters, nautical mile conversions has to be taken to consideration.This is possible in a manual calculation. but projection system or the coordinate s system of the maps used should be known.

Comment: I also found out that there is a library called geometry in google maps API which enables to do this using the method compute offset.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeOffset